# Woocommerce additional price

Tags: woocommerce, price

The way WooCommerce works is good I was wondering is there any way where I can set base price and then additional price

e.g.

Base Price: $25

Size

- Small: add $0
- Large: add $20

Comment: You need to set these products as [Variable Product](https://docs.woothemes.com/document/variable-product/)